# Connect to mysql db but no data from table is echo to screen

Tags: php, mysql

The script below connects to the db (I get the connected successfully echo) but none of the data from the query is shown onscreen.

I assume the data must be somewhere as I do not get the error message.

Question: Where is the error in the script?

```
<?php
//connectdb();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","UN","PW");
if ( $con == "" ) { echo " DB Connection error...\r\n"; exit(); }
echo 'Connected successfully';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT graduation_year FROM wp_gfsept2013");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
if ($result === "") {echo "An error occurred.";}

{
echo $row['graduation_year'];
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Appreciate any help that can be sent my way, I'm a real newbie at this stuff.
Roger

Comment: `$result` will never be equal to the empty string `""` by strict comparison `===`.  Use `if (!$result)` to test for failure and `echo mysql_error()` to see what the error actually was.

Comment: That error check should occur _before_ the `while` loop. Otherwise, the entire body of the while loop will be the error check, since it isn't enclosed by `{}`

Comment: Mix of `mysqli_` and `mysql_`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an opening brace after `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` and a closing brace before the end of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Is this not a syntax issue?? Why is there an IF clause after a WHILE clause but before the opening bracket for the WHILE loop block?

Additionally, you are trying to use mysql_fetch_array() instead of mysqli_fetch_array().

```
<?php
//connectdb();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","UN","PW");
if ( $con == "" ) { echo " DB Connection error...\r\n"; exit(); }
echo 'Connected successfully';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT graduation_year FROM wp_gfsept2013");
if ($result !== FALSE && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { // Proper way to test for results
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row['graduation_year'];
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
else {
    die("Query Returned 0 rows...");
}
?>
```

Documentation: [mysqli_result::$num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, guys.  Wes, I put your modified version up (many thanks for making the changes) but I still only get the 'Connected successfully' message.

Comment: Wes, I checked all the headings for the db, then reset to another table in the db.  When I viewed source there were 4 lines of <br/>.  I put it back as above and the first time I checked it was just the connection ok.  Next time, the data showed up!

Comment: I edited my source... I was using mysqli_fetch_array() instead of mysqli_fetch_assoc(). However, I don't believe that would cause issues according to documentation (http://us1.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array). Nevertheless, inside your while loop, perhaps a var_dump($row) could prove useful to see?